# Having problem while starting apache server

Tags: server, apache2

I have installed apache2 in my ubuntu 12.4 using `sudo apt-get install apache2`, now i am not able to start the server, when i use `service apache2 start`, following things were displayed.

```
    bharathkumar@hkbharath:~$ service apache2 start
    * Starting web server apache2                                                     
    /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
    mktemp: failed to create directory via template `/var/lock/apache2.XXXXXXXXXX': No such file or directory
    chmod: missing operand after `755'
    Try `chmod --help' for more information.
                                                                                 [fail]
```

i tried uninstalling and reinstalling apache2, but still getting the same thing, please help me to start my apache2 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem running on a virtual server.  Turns out that /var/lock is a symbolic link to /run/lock, which didn't exist.  I solved it like this:

sudo mkdir /run/lock

## Then restart Apache:

sudo service apache2 restart

Hope it works for you.

Comment: yeah i did the same thing and added the output file of `mktemp` to that folder.

Comment: Or, in my case: `ln -s /run/lock /var/lock`

Answer (score 2):

To start Apache, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

You can also try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
or
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing as i shown in the question.??
can you give me some more suggestions

Comment: Are you using sudo?

Comment: Try what I added in the answer.

Comment: Getting same messages..

Comment: Try `mktemp`, and use the output /tmp/tmp.xxxxxxxxxx to store your output.

Comment: Try 'whoami' and compare it with 'sudo whoami'.  You should *not* get the same output. The first should print your login name, the other should print root.

Comment: @Mitch i didnt get you can you elaborate that..please...
with `mktemp` i got some output tmp/tmp.DwklDe354H, what i have to do next?

Comment: As it says in your question, about not being able to create temp, just create it manually, so you can use it.  Look at [MKTEMP](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mktemp)for more info.

Comment: Hey Mitch thanks a lot i got it ....it has started now....

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: You said, that it worked for you yet you unaccepted the answer.  Just curious, why?